# How to process KML/GeoJSON in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, gis, kml, geojson

I ran out of google searches and reaching out for help here.  We are right now processing KML file using geoXml3 at client side. But Ideally I would want to pre-process it in server side and send the ploygons on the client side. Because KML file is 18MB file and it takes forever to download on client side and then client parses it and draws the polygon on google map.

We changed KML files to GeoJSON and reduced the size , compressed it - after all the circus the response time is still not good. I just want to know if there is a way / library in node that can do this.

Comment: Are you looking for a library to convert kml file to geojson?

Comment: Do you need to process the file for every request, or is this a one-time processing on the server side?

Comment: @HeadCode this is one time on load layer, we have postgis for every request

Comment: @Dario No , not looking for KML to GeoJSON

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you are compressing the file, what do you mean?  If you mean an algorithm such as zip or lha, that won't necessarily reduce the size of the file that much.  What you want to do is to remove line segments from the KML file.  In reducing some geographic information, I found that there were lengths of many miles that varied less than a foot from a straight line.  Since the data points were spaced every few feet, that meant that the vast majority of the points in the KML file could be removed without making an appreciable change in the appearance of the geometry.  Looking for straight line segments is relatively simple.

You should also keep in mind the scale of the map you are viewing and the spacing of the data points in the KML file.  Even if the lines are complex curves, it may be possible to remove large numbers of points by trying to curve fit segments of the features and reduce the size of the data in this way.

You seem to be implying that downloading the data from the server to the client takes far more time than processing the data on the server.  If this is correct, reducing the number of points is the most efficient method.

Comment: Compressing using gzip  We have reduced the points and time to download has changed from 120s to 15s. Still it seems slow! I don't think there is any solution for this

Comment: There probably isn't an easy solution or one that is generally applicable.  One approach would be to use a KML file to plot all of the points and look at it at various degrees of magnification.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tricks you can try to reduce the download & rendering time of a KML polygon file.

As already suggested in previous answers the key is to reduce the size of your data.  This can be accomplished in many ways, depending on your use case:

- Reduce the number of points that each line segment / polygon boundary is made up of.  There are plenty of algorithms for this, the [Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) line simplification algorithm is the most well known.
- Reduce the precision of your data points.  If your coordinates are stored to a high degree of precision (i.e. latitude / longitudes with several decimal places) then you can round these up to a lower degree of precision / fewer decimal places.  Note that you might have to play with this as it will make the boundary of your polygons choppy / jagged if you go too far.
- Compression.  It looks as though you have already experimented with this. Gzip compression should be able to reduce the wire payload size of KML significantly.
- Finally, if you are still not getting the results you want you could consider generalizing your data further by removing small / insignificant polygons.  Again, this will depend on your use case

Comment: Thanks Aengus , the reduced file is now 1.6 MB. But still take 15s to load which is slightly frustrating from usability prespective

Comment: Yes that is still quite slow.  Did you look into where that 15s is going? e.g. network, read, render.  Further optimizations would depend on what you are trying to do with the polygons on the client.  Have you looked at server-side rendering?